# React custom hook to display values on a select component with Typescript and Material UI

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Im trying to create an hook to render a list of countries for a dropdown with data from an endpoint that gets printed like this:

```
0: "ALA Aland Islands"
1: "Afghanistan"
2: "Albania"
3: "Algeria"
...
```

And for this im using a custom hook that gets the correct response:

```
const initCountries = {
    countries: [],
  };

  const [countries, SetCountries] = useState(initCountries);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getCountryList() {
      const response = await generalSubs.getCountriesList();
      console.log(response);
      SetCountries(response.data);
    }
    getCountryList();
  }, []);
  return countries;
```

And i create a custom dropdown component:

```
type GeneralCountryProps = {
  labelId: string;
  id: any;
  handleFieldChange: any;
  countryList: string[];
};

//const countryList = CountriesDropdown();
export const CountrySubForm: FunctionComponent<GeneralCountryProps> = ({
  labelId,
  id,
  handleFieldChange,
  countryList,
}) => (
  <Select
    labelId={labelId}
    id={id}
    value={countryList}
    onChange={handleFieldChange}
  >
    <MenuItem value={countryList}>{countryList}</MenuItem>;
  </Select>
);
```

And on the father i use the hook and the child:

```
  const countryList = CountriesDropdown();

<CountrySubForm
          labelId="country-list-label"
          id="country-List"
          handleFieldChange={handleFieldChange}
          countryList={countryList.countries}
        />
```

Yet im not seeing any countries being displayed. Any help on why please?

Comment: What does `const countryList = CountriesDropdown();` ?

Comment: 0 … 99]
0: "ALA Aland Islands"
1: "Afghanistan"
2: "Albania"

Comment: You put `countryList={countryList.countries}`, `.countries` seems not necessary if you have directly the array.

Comment: Thats not gonna work:
Type 'never[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.  TS2322

     95 |           id="country-List"
     96 |           handleFieldChange={handleFieldChange}
  >  97 |           countryList={countryList}
        |           ^
     98 |           value={""}
     99 |         />
    100 |         {console.log("countryList", countryList)}